# How to properly setup Gradle in Android Studio for ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

So I'm struggling to setup a very simple Project in Android Studio v0.2 with Gradle v1.6.
I want to create a simple app that uses ActionBarSherlock, so I created a Project in Android Studio.
In the same root folder as the Project is created, I have downloaded the latest ABS.

So here's my structure:

```
|ABSAppProject 
|..settings.gradle
|..build.gradle
|--ABSApp
|....build.gradle
|actionbarsherlock
|..build.gradle
```

In the root `settings.gradle`, I have:

```
include ':ABSApp'
include 'actionbarsherlock'
project(':actionbarsherlock').projectDir=new File('actionbarsherlock')
```

In the `actionbarsherlock/build.gradle` I have:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 14
  buildToolsVersion '17'

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
  }
}
```

And, finally in, the `ABSApp/build.gradle`, I have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:r7'
    compile project (':actionbarsherlock')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

The root build.gradle is empty.

When building, (using gradle build --info) I get:

```
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/m/Documents/Projects/ABSAppProject/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/ma/Documents/Projects/ABSAppProject/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'ABSAppProject', project ':ABSApp', project ':actionbarsherlock']
Evaluating root project 'ABSAppProject' using build file '/Users/m/Documents/Projects/ABSAppProject/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':ABSApp' using build file '/Users/m/Documents/Projects/ABSAppProject/ABSApp/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':actionbarsherlock' using empty build file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':ABSApp'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Building the ABS library alone using Gradle seems to work ok, so that gradle.build file is probably ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I'm having trouble with this too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for downloading ABS separately. Gradle supports Android's new [.aar format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) which makes using library projects easier. Just add this (or whatever version it is currently) to `dependencies` section in `build.gradle` of your project:

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

and let Gradle handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The entry for actionbarsherlock in `settings.gradle` should be

> include '..:actionbarsherlock'

you should not need `project(':actionbarsherlock').projectDir=new File('actionbarsherlock')`